# Square Connect API Refund Clarification

Tags: square-connect

If a merchant issues a refund, does it show up in both the [Refunds List](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#get-refunds) and [Retrieve Payment](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#get-paymentid) endpoint? Are there situations in which it may show up in one, but not the other (such as Cash, Check, or other Tender Types)?

The use case is an external app storing / caching payments where refunds need to update the stored payments to keep accurate sales figures. If refunds show up in both places, then it seems the best way to update stored payments in this use case is to load the Refunds List periodically and update the stored payment using the Retrieve Payment endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of tender type, every refund is available both from the List Refunds endpoint and from the List/Retrieve Payment endpoints. Your solution sounds like a good one, since the List Refunds endpoint is chronological by date of refund, as opposed to date of original payment.

You can use the `payment_id` included in the returned `Refund` objects to look up your stored copy of the corresponding payment.